# Whatsapp Cloud API Update Profile Picture

Tags: postman, cloud, whatsapp

I'm trying to upload an image as profile picture using WhatsApp Cloud API *.

> After creating an application using WhatsApp Cloud API I'm not allowed to access neither using the regular application nor using Business Application. It says something like "try again in one hour". So I have to implement everything using the API.

After reading the docs and importing [Postman Endpoints](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/13382743/UVC5FTHT#intro) I found the one called **Business Profiles > Update Business Profile**

`https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/whatsapp_business_profile`

It has a field `"profile_picture_url"`and I have tried POSTing media `https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/media` and then with the given ID y used `https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Media-ID}}` to get the URL but it didn't work. The rest of the information is updated successfully

```
{
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "address": "",
    "description": "Simple Bot",
    "email": "...@gmail.com",
    "websites": [
        "https://..."
    ],
    "profile_picture_url": "https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/..."
}
```

However if I try to send someone using the ID and the endpoint `https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages` it works fine.
And if I use *Download Media Content* with the URL in Postman it works fine too.

I don't know if I have misunderstood something or if it can't be done using the API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mentioned in the [Cloud API Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/business-profiles):

> profile_picture_url (Optional): URL of the profile picture generated from a call to the [Resumable Upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload).

But, i got it working using `profile_picture_handle` instead of `profile_picture_url`. So how do we get the `profile_picture_handle`?

Prerequisite:

1. Graph API token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Or use your WhatsApp Cloud API token.
2. App ID, go [Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) > Your App > Settings (sidebar menu) > Basic

Update Photo Profile:

1. Call `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{{appId}}/uploads?access_token={{token}}&file_length={{fileSizeInByte}}&file_type=image/jpeg`
2. Save the session id you got, `upload:XXXXXX?sig=XXXXXX`.
3. Call `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{{sessionId}}`, with the headers: `Authorization=OAuth {{token}}, file_offset=0, Host=graph.facebook.com, Connection=close, Content-Type=multipart/form-data`, and include your image file in the request body with type binary. If you using Postman, see image below (This is what I missed for hours). [image]
4. Save the handle result you got, `4::XXX==:XXXXXX`.
5. Finally, call `POST https://graph.facebook.com/{{Version}}/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/whatsapp_business_profile`, with json request body: `{"messaging_product": "whatsapp", "profile_picture_handle": "4::XXX==:XXXXXX"}`

That's it, You can check the profile picture.

Comment: I can't get step 5 to go through.

Comment: Uuurghh!! Meta APIs are overly complicated for no reason. Why call three different endpoints just to upload a picture? On top of this there is a token and three other user specific variables, and a Facebook developer account with password and 2FA??

Comment: It works. I got the profile picture updated. Thank you.~

Answer (score -2):

The last step you have to add your taken by selecting "Bearer" or else it will give you error. I had hard time on the last ones, do all the steps and then go to the following link and it should help.

[https://web.postman.co/workspace/My-Workspace~a4ddb3b8-02a3-4132-8384-66e63e149b7b/request/22958165-506a0542-c845-41ac-b3fb-b8209fd6f53b](https://web.postman.co/workspace/My-Workspace%7Ea4ddb3b8-02a3-4132-8384-66e63e149b7b/request/22958165-506a0542-c845-41ac-b3fb-b8209fd6f53b)